# Report Server ( [162] Internal request to deactivate schedule ) error ( SQL Server 2008 R2 )

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs

This is the error:

> [162] Internal request (from SetJobNextRunDate [reason: schedule will
>   not run again]) to deactivate schedule N

The Image:

[image: problem]

Has anyone seen this? I have no idea what is this error.

When we Schedule a task to send an e-mail with report server, it shows me this error in error log.

There are a lot of websites saying it is a SQL 2005 BUG. But I can't find nothing to help me with SQL Server 2008 R2.

**EDIT 1**

Digging a little more...I could find this:

[image: Mail error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct, there was bug in earlier version saying

> "If you set up a SQLAgent job to have a recurring weekly schedule, the
>   job executes successfully the first day, but may later become disabled
>   and the job may not run the next day and thereafter."

But later also, quite a few have reported and it worked for them once they upgraded to SP2+( Sql Server 2008R2), so depends what SP are you running as of now:

Also,

This error may occur if you have a duplicate schedule. Say for the job in question there are various steps and some steps may have the schedule with similar name , even though different timings, but still same name on schedule step also has witnessed the above error. See for any such miss.

Moreover, see [here](http://mssqlwiki.com/tag/sql-server-resource-failure/) if this helps.

Comment: But..What is "mail session"? We figure out our SMTP server was bad. We fixed it, but even restarting SQL AGENT ,We can send reports, and this error above persists.